# How to process default @RequestMapping() action by "params" value?

Tags: spring, controller

My controller actions are selected for execution by `params` value from HTTP request, something like that:

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/action",
            params = "foo=bar"
    )
```

It works but I need to have one "default" action that will be executed when no other action is selected by `params` setting. I tried to use action without `params` but such action is executed on every HTTP request.

**Q:** How to create method that will process not selected requests?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the parameters of the mapped request accept style expressions.

You can for example define :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action", params = "!foo")
```

to indicate that the specified parameter `foo` is not supposed to be present in the request.

Comment: There is more methods that are mapped to request parameters. I cannot use this technique.

Comment: Or you can use  `@RequestMapping("*")` to have a default mapping.